# HTML page integrate with razor engine layout view in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

We are developing a web application in **MVC4**.  The layout view name is `layout.cshtml` which is cshtml file (Razor engine) and we did several essential things (such as login div) in layout view. Recently a requirement has met that we need to **integrate several static HTML page** with this MVC4 web application. The problem that we face is,

- It is compulsory that users who view the static HTML  also need to access to this login div. So the **master pages of all those static HTML must be `layout.cshtml`**.
- Since we code several other views in this application which depends on this layout, we **can't change the layout from CSHTML to HTML**.

Considering these scenario, how can we integrate those HTML pages having master page as `layout.cshtml` with this web application. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed partial view [partial view demo](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC) with the Html (only the html into body), it is one clean way to achieve what you want if I did well understood your problem.

You just ave to put the static html into "_static.cshtml" without razor if you want and then include it by using

```
@Html.Partial("_static")
```

I also recommand you to make partialview with the login form too, your layout.cshtml  could be more clear for editing

If you want to handle lots of partial, then you can use only one controller and use one string.. something like this:

List of available pages

```
<ul>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("page1", "GetStatic", "Home", new { name = "page1" }, null)
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("page2", "GetStatic", "Home", new { name = "page2" }, null)
    </li>
</ul>
```

Controller hitten by clicking on list items:

```
public ActionResult GetStatic(string name)
        {
            if(name .IsNotNull())
            {
                return View(model:name);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

GetStatic.cshtml:

```
@model String

@Html.partial("@Model")
```

Comment: Thanks clement for replying. Actually, `layout.cshtml` is the master page we used in the web application. So i need to attach this master page with the static HTML

Comment: Once again @Sumithlal I'm not sure of what you want. Layout contains all header footer and _static will host one or more div, isn't it? if thar is correctyou can use partial with static.cshtml or somethine else name as I recommand. if not, please provide us more information (basic code of layout and the "static" html that you want to integrate,...

Comment: Hi clement, you told that "_You just ave to put the static html into '_static.cshtml' without razor if you want and then include it by using `@Html.Partial("_static")`..._". Where should i include those code? I think, for that i need to create another view file. It may be very difficult since i have more than 40 static page to integrate. Thank you for responding.

Comment: @Sumithal if you have 40 pages to integrate, you must integrate them all, it's just about renaming .html to .cshtml, I didn't see the difficulty. If there is, please copy paste the layout and one of the "static" page in the question to understand because it's complicated with the only explanation that you gave

Comment: But the problem there is, when it is changed as `*.cshtml` file, i need to create 40 action method to call all those views.

Comment: do I mentionned that @Html.Partial("_static") needs a controller?

Comment: Without controller, how can i call cshtml view?

Comment: @Sumithal This is not JS or even JQuery, this is RAZOR Synthax that include another razor page. You can call partial view with ajax or you can include them directly in razor, by using Html.Partial . Try this and you will understand

Comment: Static HTML can call directly with its name in URL. As you said, If I change all these HTML to razor view, I need to create action methods for each razor. It will be a huge work for me because there are so many HTML in this case. So I need to call those page with its name (as HTML)  with appending the master page(cshtml) that i created before for my MVC application.

Comment: Have you difficulties with english or it's me that have trouble with? NO NEED OF CONTROLLER/METHOD with Html.Partial, it justs include the html file without using Controller, just an include!

Comment: `Html.Partial` just include html file in cshtml. Then how should i call this cshtml file?

Comment: @Sumithal Question = How can we integrate those HTML pages having layout as layout.cshtml with this web application. Here you're asking a new question, let's say I will respond to that question... But you didn't gave enough information to respond to you. Please clarify your question, then I will understand and help you. Stupid examples could be the solution because I see that you have trouble to explain it by words...

Comment: I have a feeling that what @Sumithlal meant was that he wanted make his `layout.chtml`  the master page of his 40 odd static HTML pages. @Sumithlal kindly confirm if what I said is true so that we can probe in the right direction.

Comment: yes @antony.ouseph.k that is exactly what I want. I know that if I make these 40+ static pages `.cshtml` and add `layout.cshtml` as the master page, it would work. However, in order to do this, I will need 40+ action methods which returns these view. I would like to know if there is any other way.

Comment: @Sumithlal now I understand. I am familiar only with the method u mentioned where u have several action methods returning your views. Even I am curious to know if there is any other way.

Comment: @Sumithlal 1 static page represent 1 whole page content? only one static page by content?

Comment: @clement Yes. 1 static page represent 1 whole page. There are 40 such static pages are there.

Comment: @Sumithlal my answer does it respond to your question?

Comment: @Sumithlal cool perfect, you can remove thepain to integrate that html so :-)